# Why don't I see Principal Name when I run az role assignment list from Azure Devops?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, az

I m running **az role assignment list -g**  from Azure Devops on Microsofts Hosted Agent

I dont see principalName parameter in result. But same command when I run on my local in VsCode I see principalName. I checked az cli versions  both MS agent and on my local, they are same 2.5.1

Wondering what I m missing....

below is what i get in Azure Devops after running the above command

```
{
    "canDelegate": xxx,
    "id": xxx,
    "name": xxx,
    "principalId": xxx,
    "principalType": xxx,
    "resourceGroup": xxx,
    "roleDefinitionId": xxx,
    "scope": xxx,
    "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments"
}
```

Comment: can you try az role assignment list --resource-group rgname

Comment: same , it doesnt have principleName. It works fine in cloudshell though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft helped to resolve this issue. Your Service Principal needs Directory Read access on App Permissions. This would solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Why don't I see Principal Name when I run az role assignment list from Azure Devops?

I could reproduce this issue with `Azure CLI` task on my side.

I found there is a [similar issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/6945) about the `Azure cli` on the github, so, I am afraid this issue has not been fixed on the `azure cli` task, it still exists.

To resolve/verify this issue, you could try to use the Azure Powershell task to login and execute that command line:

```
az login -u <username> -p <password>

az role assignment list --resource-group rgname
```

The result:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks a lot , the link mentioned really helps with information. will try with Azure Powershell task.

Comment: @Suraj, I haven't received your reply for a long time. Can I know if this answer is valid for you?

Comment: i have whole big script written in python using az cli commands in it. And i m using service principal in my pipeline (avoiding user/password) for security reasons.I have raised it with MS just waiting for their reply...