# Unable to query 'principalName' via azure-cli when authenticated as a Service Principal

Tags: azure, azure-cli

If I perform `az login` as myself, I'm able to see the following output:

```
(.venv) supertonic09 % az role assignment list --subscription aa11bb33-cc77-dd88-ee99-0918273645aa --role "Owner" --query '[*].principalName'
[
  "zeus@test.onmicrosoft.com",
  "pluto@test.onmicrosoft.com",
  "poseidon@test.onmicrosoft.com"
]
```

…but if leverage the `--service-principal` option, as I'm attempting to develop a check via Python, while I get other values like `id`, `name`, and `roleDefinitionName` for example… I'm still oddly missing `principalName` from my query.

Please note, that based on [Why don't I see Principal Name when I run az role assignment list from Azure Devops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61787397/why-dont-i-see-principal-name-when-i-run-az-role-assignment-list-from-azure-dev), I've added `Directory.Read.All` but the result is still the same.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You you need `Azure AD Graph Directory.Read.All` —not to be confused with just `Microsoft Graph Directory.Read.All`